# How are programming paradigms classified?

Tags: programming-languages, object-oriented, programming-paradigms

When I started to learn about imperative programming and declarative programming it raised many doubts, like, how are structured, modular and object-oriented programming classified: declarative or imperative?

Comment: There are too many questions here. Please consider breaking it down into a number of questions.

Comment: I've cleaned up the question a little bit and reduced it to a single question. The other two questions were incomprehensible to me, so I deleted them. Please feel free to ask them again, paying more attention to how they are phrased.

Answer (score 4):

Do not be too obsessed with it. It is often only buzzwords covering a
fuzzy trend (from structured to object oriented) towards better
organization of programs, with somewhat different realizations in
different languages. It can appear in any programming paradigm,
whether imperative or declarative. They are intended to improve
readability of programs, good programming practice, maintainability,
code reuse in various guises, independence of program parts,
information hiding.

What is a lot more important is to understand the specific techniques
that can be used, their costs and benefits, the constraints they
create and the freedom they provide. The more interesting techniques
are based on formal mathematical analysis.

It involves a variety of more precisely definable concepts, such as
environments, scoping and binding of variables, typing systems,
modularity and interfacing, parameterization of code and modules,
exception handling ...

I would think you will be better off concentrating on these identified
technical issues than on more popular but fuzzier concept.